# Loop through a list of dictionaries and print only those items with specific value?

Tags: string, loops, dictionary, printing

Newbie here :) I've been tasked with project to print only those items in the list of dictionaries that have a status of "Tombstone". Here is an example of the list:

Configuration =

"configs": [
{
"_id": "my_ID3",
"channel_name": "I love lucy",
"content_owner": "NEW ID",
"country": "US",
"service_id": "ABCD",
"status": "ReadyForTesting"
},
{
"_id": "my_ID2",
"channel_name": "Donkey Kong",
"content_owner": "NEW ID",
"country": "US",
"service_id": "EFG",
"status": "ReadyForTesting"
},
{
"_id": "my_ID1",
"channel_name": "PacMan",
"content_owner": "Pac Productions",
"country": "US",
"service_id": "1234",
"status": "Sunset"
}

What is the best way in Python to go through the list an only print those channel IDs(with all of the configurations) that have a status of "Sunset"? Note: there are other other status, but just need to remove those that have "Sunset". Hope the above information is enough to help explain the steps needed. Appreciate your help :)

Currently, still trying to figure out the approach.

for config in configs:
if "status" != "Sunset"
return config

print(config[_id], config[channel_name, config[content_owner], config[country],config[service_id],config[status)

expected results:
Goal is print only those channel configurations that DO NOT have "Sunset"
{
"_id": "my_ID3",
"channel_name": "I love lucy",
"content_owner": "NEW ID",
"country": "US",
"service_id": "ABCD",
"status": "ReadyForTesting"
},
{
"_id": "my_ID2",
"channel_name": "Donkey Kong",
"content_owner": "NEW ID",
"country": "US",
"service_id": "EFG",
"status": "ReadyForTesting"